# Grails: HTML anchors inside of nested each loops

Tags: html, grails, anchor, each, gsp

I am coding a project in Grails of faq links that will have a section at the top where the user will click the question link, and it will take them to the question/answer section below, then allow them to return to the top.  I've done this in HTML before, but have never put these kinds of anchors into a  loop before.    Just wanted to know if I'm anywhere close to right.  :)

Does the anchor tag itself need to be iterated also?  For example, I need to be able to click on question #1 at the top and know it will take me to the correct question/answer at the bottom.  Right now I only have a few short faqs to test, so it's hard to see what will happen once I get a bunch in there...
Here's what I have so far..

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <g:each in="${...FaqCategory.list()}" var="faqCategory">
        <p><b>${faqCategory.categoryType}</b></p>
        <a name="top"></a>
        <g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" var="faq" status="i">
            <p>${i+1}. <a href="#question">${faq.question}?</p></a>
        </g:each>
    </g:each>
    <p></p>

    <g:each in="${...FaqCategory.list()}" var="faqCategory">
        <p><b>${faqCategory.categoryType}</b></p>
        <g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" var="faq" status="i">
            <a name="question"><p>${i+1}. ${faq.question}?</p></a> 
            <ul><p>Answer: ${faq.answer} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [<a href="#top">return to top</a>]</ul></p>
        </g:each>
    </g:each>
    <p></p>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want it to be as below:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <g:each in="${...FaqCategory.list()}" var="faqCategory">
        <p><b>${faqCategory.categoryType}</b></p>
        <a name="top"></a>
        <g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" 
                var="faq" status="i">
            <p>${i+1}. <a href="#${faq.question}">${faq.question}?</p></a>
        </g:each>
    </g:each>
    <p></p>

    <g:each in="${...FaqCategory.list()}" var="faqCategory">
        <p><b>${faqCategory.categoryType}</b></p>
        <g:each in="${Faq.findAllByFaqCategory(faqCategory)}" 
                var="faq" status="i">
            <a name="${faq.question}"><p>${i+1}. ${faq.question}?</p></a> 
            <ul><p>Answer: ${faq.answer} 
                   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                   [<a href="#top">return to top</a>]</p></ul>
        </g:each>
    </g:each>
    <p></p>     
</div>
```

Note the changes in both the anchor tags. Also note, if you have `ids` for corresponding questions that that can be used as anchors instead of the question itself.